# bootstrap not included in compiled css using gulp and browser-sync

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-sass

Bootstrap not included in my compiled CSS file when compiling using Gulp and Browser-sync. I'm trying to compile both my custom SCSS files and Bootstrap SCSS files.

I've tried commenting out some SCSS files but only the custom ones (my own SCSS files) are added to the compiled CSS.

```
const gulp        = require("gulp");
const sass        = require("gulp-sass");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
const cleanCSS    = require('gulp-clean-css');
const rename      = require("gulp-rename");

// Compile SCSS into CSS

function style() {
  // 1. location of SCSS files
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
  // 2. pass that file through the sass compiler
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  // 3. rename the output
    .pipe(rename('custom-style.css'))
  // 3. location of saved CSS file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
  // 5. minify and check compatibility
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
  // 6. rename to .min
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  // 7. add to app/css directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
  // 4. stream changes to all browsers
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app/'
    }
  });
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', style);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Directory:

```
project-folder
|-- app
    |-- scss
        |-- bootstrap
            |-- bootstrap.scss
        |-- stylesheets
            |-- custom.scss
        |-- app.scss
    |-- css
        |-- custom-style.css
        |-- custom-style.min.css
    |-- node_modules
        |-- gulp_packages
        |-- bootstrap
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

Inside bootstrap.scss:

```
 /*!
 * Bootstrap v4.3.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2019 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2019 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/print";
```

I don't have any errors when running gulp watch. The only SCSS files included during the compilation is just my custom SCSS files.

Gulp:
CLI Version: 2.2.0
Local Version: 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the `gulp.src` from `gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')` to `gulp.src('app/scss/app.scss')`.

But I still don't know why `gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')` won't work.